# Using grep with symbolic link

Tags: grep, symlink

I don't know how to ask this, but let me explain.

I have a text file (named `bla`) in my `~/user/Dropbox` folder. I would like to `grep` on it from any folder in terminal.

For example, I'd like just type `grep 'foo' bla` instead of going to `~/user/Dropbox` to look for.

I believe that some symbolic link could help. Any idea?

Comment: @sputnick, sorry but I have no idea about what you're saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can give the full path to grep:

```
grep foo ~/user/Dropbox/bla
```

Or you could add a function on your ~/.bashrc file, so you won't need to type the full path:

```
dgrep(){
    grep "$1" "~/user/Dropbox/$2"
}
```

Running the function (after you open a new shell or run `. .bashrc`):

```
dgrep foo bla
```

EDIT: `dgrep` is a tool contained in `debian-goodies` that *searches all files in specified packages for a regex*. It should be safe to use this name if you don't use Debian or are not an advanced user. Otherwise, change `dgrep` to something else.

Comment: +1. Thanks so much. Since I'll `grep` on the same file everytime, I defined a function (called `busca`, which means *find* in my language) only with one argument so I just call `busca foo`.

Comment: Good for interpreting correctly what the question was about!